# WW2 submarine yarn with 10 or 12 "Bermuda" type triangles

Tags: story-identification, novel, warfare

I'm trying to recall the name of a book from the 70's in which a submarine is lost in WW2 off the coast of Japan and returns 30 (or so) years later, crewless, off the coast of Hawaii. The Navy refits it and tries to recreate its final war cruise after finding the sole survivor, now a scientist, who claims there are actually 10 or twelve "Bermuda" type triangles including one in the area where the sub went down and one where it reappeared...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Ghostboat*](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=ghostboat) aka *Ghost Boat* by George E. Simpson and Neal R. Burger. Besides those reviews at amazon.com, you can read plot synopses by some of the booksellers at [abebooks.com](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=0&bx=off&ds=30&recentlyadded=all&sortby=17&sts=t&tn=ghostboat&x=93&y=20), like this one from bookseller [Past Pages](http://www.abebooks.com/past-pages-oshawa-on-canada/8557964/sf):

> SYNOPSIS: December 11, 1944 - U.S.S. Candlefish, submarine on wartime patrol, mysteriously lost at Latitude 30 Degrees N in the Pacific. All hands perish, except for one survivor. October 5, 1974 - Six hundred miles northwest of Pearl Harbor, a submarine surfaces in front of a Japanese freighter. It is the Candlefish, in perfect working order, fully outfitted down to steaks in the freezer, yet without a trace of life aboard. In Washington, D.C., a naval intelligence officer convinces his superiors that this is a golden opportunity to prove his theory that another Devil's Triangle exists where the Candlefish originally went down. His plan is to take the Candlefish on a voyage retracing her route of thirty years before, and at last uncover whatever fearful forces lies in wait at Latitude 30 Degrees. Only when the sub is well out to sea, with no turning back, do he and the rest of the crew begin to suspect why the Candlefish has come back from a watery grave, and what that means to every living soul aboard. - and - Survivor - The last time Jack Hardy had seen the Candlefish, he had been a young Navy lieutenant, fighting for his life in the waters of the Pacific while his submarine was torn apart by violent tremors and gigantic charges of electrical energy. Now Jack Hardy was back aboard the Candlefish, a middle-aged man haunted by nightmares of a war concluded long ago, and by the memory of a voyage that had almost destroyed him as a man. Only Jack Hardy knew what had happened aboard the Candlefish thirty years before. Only he at first recognized what was happening now. And somehow he had to find a way to do now what he had not been able to do then. Somehow he had to change the course of the satanic drama that was inexorably unfolding - or he would not survive a second time . . .

The book was made into a 2006 British TV movie [*Ghostboat*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostboat) which you can watch online, e.g. [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWRyyUVKXXY).

By the way, I found this answer by reposting the question to the [BookSleuth Forum](http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/abesleuthcom?) at abebooks.com, where the book was identified by "madauthor".

Comment: +1 and the cigar. That is it. I wanted to reread it. Being able to watch it is quite a bonus.

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy. That British TV movie seems to have changed some of the story from the book, such as the name & nationality of the boat and the location.